# Package manager to install emacs24.5.1 on linux mint

Tags: linux, emacs, installation, linux-mint

I'm trying to get the latest stable release of emacs on linux mint (emacs-24.5).  But, for some reason apt-get only installs 24.3.1.  I would usually be OK with that, but i'm trying to use spacemacs, and alot of the packages require at least 24.4.  I've tried installing it myself, but ./configure doesn't work (It says I need a whole bunch of libraries, and those libraries need a whole bunch of libraries...), I tried to install it without the libraries, and it only make a bad looking text based terminal only version.  I even tried using linuxbrew, but I couldn't find out how to get the gui working, since I couldn't just do:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

I noticed that ubuntu comes with emacs 24.5, and i'm willing to install that operating system, since i've only been using linux mint for a day.  But is there any way I can get emacs 24.4 or 24.5 on mint?  A different package manager, something to install all the libraries that the manual make requires.  Also I have already tried these tutorials and none of them worked: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/emacs-24-4-released-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/
and most of the ones on stack overflow.  When I tried to install it myself, it gave me an error about X and gtk or some other window library, even after I did what all the tutorials said to do to get X libraries.  Thanks for any help and sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this kind of question.  Also, ask me if I need to specify what errors I got etc...

Comment: How about using the Emacs PPA at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?

Comment: Ironically, that installs emacs 25.1.50.2, which doesn't support spacemacs either.  either too high or too low :(

Comment: That is unfortunate. The GitHub README for spacemacs does say that "Emacs 25, is not officially supported but is partially working (i.e. bugs should be expected)", so it _may be_ sufficiently functional for what you need to do. Otherwise, you probably need to compile from source and figure out why `./configure` didn't work for you. [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place for questions like this.

Comment: I did compile from source, and the error was that it could find the x-toolkit, even after I installed the libraries, I couldn't figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Try asking on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead; asking how to compile from source is possibly off-topic in SO.